# Откуда пошло выражение: "счастья (радости) полные штаны"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Ничего пока толком не нашла. Сниженное от "полная чаша"? Далековато.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то подобные выражения самодостаточны, искать первоисточник нет надобности.
Чаша, конечно, здесь ни при чем. "Полные штаны" - это, пардон, от справления естественных надобностей непосредственно в оные штаны.